# flutter/dart static list or list of singleton object always return it's default values when calling it from another class

Tags: flutter, dart

i am trying to use static list as global variable that can be accessible through all the dart classes , so i have done like that:

```
class MyData {

   // initialize it to an empty list
   static var List<MyObject> myObjectList = new List<MyObject>();

}
```

then in another class I load that empty list with list of MyObject (**no doubt that it loaded with success**)

**I do add objects to that list , the list will not remain empty !!**

when it comes the time to use the myObjectList in another class it returns  an empty list with 0 length

```
class SomeClass {

   .....

   void getMyObjectsList(){
      .....
      // this display 0 length and has no data 
      print("my static object list length == ${MyData.myObjectList.length}");
   }

}
```

i have also tried using a singleton instance and it return the same result :

```
class MyData {

    static final MyData _singleton = MyData._internal();

    factory MyData() {
      return _singleton;
    }

    MyData._internal();

   // object property
   var List<MyObject> myObjectList = new List<MyObject>();

}
```

well this also return the default value which is an empty list:

```
class SomeClass {

   .....

   void getMyObjectsList(){
      ....
      // this display 0 length and has no data 
      print("my singleton object list length == ${MyData().myObjectList.length}");
   }

}
```

Comment: Is that all the relevant code you have inside the `MyData` class? If so, then this is the expected behaviour, as you instantiate `myObjectList` with an empty list

Comment: you should add some data into your list before accessing the list and try again may be this will help you.

Answer (score 2):

I think you missed to Store/Copy/Add objects in the List

```
class MyData {
   // initialize it to an empty list
   static List<MyObject> myObjectList = [];
}
```

Add some Objects to List before accessing the List

```
class SomeClass {

   .....

/// Add Object to List using this Method
    void addDataToList(MyObject data){
        myObjectList.add(data);
    }

   void getMyObjectsList(){
      .....
      // this display 0 length and has no data 
      print("my static object list length == ${MyData.myObjectList.length}");
   }

}
```

Note : if there is no Data list will return 0
so please add some data before using the .length() on List.

Hope this Solve your Issue

Answer (score 0):

the problem was not in the static list , it was inside the **TextField onTap event** , 
i was using the static list inside it so i tried to use a local variable and i faced the same problem , the variable return the default value always.